# Magento 2 getName() of a variation item returns name of parent

Tags: magento2.3, orders, order-details

I am trying to print the name of an item inside an order in Magento 2.3.3.
The item is a variation, and for some reason `$item->getName()` doesn't return the full name of the item. Instead it returns some kind of a general name, like the parent of the variation or something.

This is the data from mysql from this item. The correct name is #1, but the `getName()` returns #2.

[image]

This is the code:

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->loadByIncrementId($OrderNumber);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item){
    echo "item:".$item->getName()."\n";
}
```

I tried some other ways to get the correct name,such as `getData('name')`. Also `$item->getProductOptions()['simple_name']` both return the wrong name. Another thing that I tried is getting the name of the parent of the item:

```
$product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
if(isset($product[0])){
    $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product[0]);
    $name = $product->getName();
}
```

### UPDATE

The item is a variation item ('configuable').
The main item is ID:1557, SKU:1109
One of the variations is ID:197, SKU:11096

My issue that even when I get product id 197, I am still getting the name of the parent item. How can I get the name of the item itself?

[image]

```
$product_t = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(197);
echo $product_t->getSku()."\n";   //===> 11096 (correct)
echo $product_t->getName()."\n";  //===> תיק רחצה נתלה (wrong, name of parent variation)
```

### UPDATE 2

I have found a mysql query that returns the real name of the item:

```
select value from catalog_product_entity_varchar left join eav_attribute on
eav_attribute.attribute_id = catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id
where
eav_attribute.attribute_code='name' and
catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id=197
```

result[0] is the name of the variation that I am looking for:

[image]

Anyone knows how to do the same in code?

Comment: I have no idea but you can look into store part too.

Answer (score 0):

Although using object manager is not a good practice but just to guide you I'm using it. Change it into dependency method if it works.
Add below code :

```
  $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);
  $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    $item->getItemId();
    $item->getOrderId();
    $item->getStoreId();
    $item->getProductId();

    print_r($item->getProductOptions());

    $item->getSku();
    $item->getName();
    $item->getQtyOrdered();
    $item->getPrice();
```

For details visit this [link](https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-order-information-by-order-id-in-magento-2/). hope it helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing and the `getName()` returns the wrong name

Comment: Did you try with `\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it now. Same issue. This looks like an issue with the item data, not the order data.

Comment: Though the above solution should work but if it's not then perhaps you can try getting productId from $item and then get corresponding name from product catalog?

Comment: I updated the question with some additional info. Maybe it helps?

Comment: You can check the order item data directly by looking at the `sales_order_item` table. If the name there is wrong, it implies that somewhere along the way the wrong name got used (either when the quote item was created from the product, or when the order item was created from the quote.)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is your store view level data. Here is an example of getting product:

```
$order = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);
$productObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$product = $productObj->getById($productId, false, $order->getStoreId());
```

Not tested code but you can modify it in your way.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried it right now, and it is still returning the wrong title.

Comment: I updated the question with some additional info. Maybe it helps?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked:

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $product_obj = $item->getProduct();
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
    $name = $product_obj->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($productId,'name',0);
    echo "name:$name\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the Simple Product name in Shipment emails instead of the Configurable name. Same issue as you had - ID & Sku are correct but name is not. This code doesn't work for me. Did anyone else have a solution?